# emacs map several keystrokes and command to one key

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to map `c-u m-x indent-pp-sexp` to a single key, like F5, *so that working with Emacs doesnt erode my fingerprints.*

I use `(global-set-key (kbd "C-u M-x indent-pp-sexp") "<f5>")` but i'm getting the following error:

```
global-set-key: Key sequence C-u M-x i n d e n t - p p - s e x p starts with non-prefix key C-u
```

**EDIT**

With this lambda function `(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") (lambda (interactive) (universal-argument) (indent-pp-sexp t)))`

Getting error:

```
recursive-edit: Wrong type argument: commandp, (lambda (interactive) (universal-argument) (indent-pp-sexp t))
```

Weird, because `univeral-argument` takes no parameters, and `indent-pp-sexp` takes boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the arguments the wrong way around, and you bind keys to functions, not to other key sequences. Perhaps you are really looking for a [named macro](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Keyboard-Macro.html); or you can write some actual Lisp and bind that to F5:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>")
                (function (lambda () (interactive) (indent-pp-sexp t) )) )
```

The presence of an argument in the call form appears to be sufficient to select the prefix argument functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the argument list to the lambda.  Additionally I think passing `t` to `indent-pp-sexp` negates the need to call `universal-argument`.

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") #'(lambda ()
                                 (interactive)
                                 (indent-pp-sexp t)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob like you, but I already happened to figure basic things like making macros. I don't really know what's wrong with your code, but here's walkthrough of how I do things at home. What you need to do first, is press `F3`. Then type your keystrokes, and when finished, press `F4`. Congratulations, you have defined an anonymous macro. You can replay it as many times you wish by pressing `F4` again. When you have played enough, enter `M-x name-last-keybord-macro`, and name it eg. `foobar`. Go to your `~/.emacs.d/macros/` directory (make it if you don't have one) and visit a file that you will name `foobar.el`. In its buffer, `M-x insert-kbd-macro`. When asked about name, say `foobar`. You will see that emacs has entered the contents of your just recorded macro into the file. Save it. Open your `.emacs` file, and add lines:

```
 (load (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/macros/foobar.el"))
 (global-set-key (kbd "M-<f5>") 'foobar)
```

And things start working for me after restart, with `M-F5` as the binding for `foobar.el` macro.